# Why does Array.prototype.join() flatten an array of any depth?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, join

Messing around with some JavaScript and what I thought should have produced a bug happened to work out as intended. `[].join()` seems to flatten a nested array of any depth.

```
var arr = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']];
arr.join('-'); // => 'a-b-c'
```

And even `var arr = [['a'], [[[[[[[[['b']]]]]]]]], ['c']];` returns the exact same result as above.

Which is especially odd since it returns the expected (erroneous) behavior with objects:

```
var arr = [{}, {}, {}];
arr.join('-'); // => '[object Object]-[object Object]-[object Object]'
```

Curious if this is a feature of the latest chrome (53.0.2785.116), intended, or a bug?

Comment: [_The elements of the array are converted to Strings, and these Strings are then concatenated, separated by occurrences of the separator._](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a result of the default `toString` behavior on `['a']` resulting in `'a'`. It follows that `[['a']].toString()` **also** results in `'a'`. Playing around with this in the console should make this clear. You would see a difference if your arrays had multiple elements, because `['a', 'b'].toString()` would result in `'a,b'`.

Answer (score 1):

For each element in the array that's being joined, the first thing that happens is that the element is coerced to a string. Something like

```
[[[[["b"]]]]]
```

when coerced to a string will just be

```
"b"
```

So when you do the join, the constituent elements will be forced to be strings before the join process does its thing of gluing the elements together.